# Behaviour of pushing, deleting and repushing an image in a docker registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have some strange behaviour with my docker registry.
I check the space of my container:

```
/ # du -sh
32.5M
```

Now I push a new image:

```
$ docker push myreg:5000/proj1/base:1.2
The push refers to a repository [myreg:5000/proj1/base]
89626147d178: Pushed
3fe9f0ce23f5: Layer already exists
f59b7e59ceaa: Layer already exists
1.2: digest: sha256:effd45285012fdcc8ba7137a714d12f739abc372cd284ebcc079d083449edee3 size: 953
```

Than I recheck the space:

```
/ # du -sh
62.8M
```

Okay this is normal.
Now I manually delete a the manifest of this image (`curl -XDELETE http://my-reg:5000/v2/proj1/base/manifests/1.2 seems not to work`)
(if some knows a better way...)
So I do:

```
/var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2/repositories/proj1/base/_manifests/revisions/sha256 # ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root            17 Aug 23 09:50 effd45285012fdcc8ba7137a714d12f739abc372cd284ebcc079d083449edee3
```

This is the manifest which is created at the time I pushed the image. I'm deleting it:

```
rm -r effd45285012fdcc8ba7137a714d12f739abc372cd284ebcc079d083449edee3
```

The space is the same

```
/ # du -sh
62.8M
```

I use the GC to delete unused layers/stuff + recheck space:

```
/bin/registry garbage-collect  /etc/docker/registry/config.yml
INFO[0000] Deleting blob: /docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/45/45d78757942e9b4a09f74611cc8e1f61afe8dd2cd55996f4383534279dc49418  go.version=go1.6.3 instance.id=6dbf83a9-02da-40f3-adca-8a57cf697bea
INFO[0000] Deleting blob: /docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/c9/c9513f9342779b701e300b83f7409af763352751d50f06a8708eab3bf2980164  go.version=go1.6.3 instance.id=6dbf83a9-02da-40f3-adca-8a57cf697bea
INFO[0000] Deleting blob: /docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/ef/effd45285012fdcc8ba7137a714d12f739abc372cd284ebcc079d083449edee3  go.version=go1.6.3 instance.id=6dbf83a9-02da-40f3-adca-8a57cf697bea
/ # du -sh
32.5M   .
/ #
```

This is fine! But when I repush the same image:
It goes very fast and it tells me the layer already exists:

```
89626147d178: Layer already exists
3fe9f0ce23f5: Layer already exists
f59b7e59ceaa: Layer already exists
```

The same revision is back in my manifests.
I check the space:

```
/ # du -sh
32.5M
```

Why is this not growing again and why is this going so fast (isn't it throwed away by the GC)?
The space is used here `/bin/registry`(from where I run the GC) and not in `/var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256` where I would expect it (and where it's used when I just push a new image).

```
/bin # du -sh /bin/registry
26.0M   /bin/registry
```